# How open app from iOS 8 today extension

Tags: ios8

I'm trying to open the app from the today extensions in the notification center, i have tried with the scheme url, but seems that i can't use is in the extensions, because:

```
[UIApplication sharedapplication]
```

doesn't work. how i can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should solve your problem:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"testMe://"];
[self.extensionContext openURL:url completionHandler:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Add button to the Storyboard in the extension

Add CFBundleURLSchemes so you can open app with url "weatherapp:"

Call openURL

```
@IBAction func buttonOpen_Action(sender: AnyObject) {
    /*
    Add to APP Info.plist
    <plist version="1.0">
        <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
                <array>
                    <string>weatherapp</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </array>
        </dict>
    </plist>

    */
    let context = self.extensionContext
    if let url = NSURL(string:"weatherapp:"){

        context?.openURL(url, completionHandler: { (Bool) -> Void in
            print("weatherapp:open done.")
        })

    }else{
        print("ERROR: weatherapp: not supported")
    }
}
```